# Using Javalin with SSL

Tags: java, ssl, servlets, https, jetty

I'm trying to setup Javalin with SSL support and the cert should be "secure". (Moved from https://github.com/tipsy/javalin/issues/561)

First, I create a file which contains the private key which is named `cert.cer`.

Then I execute this command
`openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile cert.cer -out certificate.p7b`

Then I insert the p7b to my keyfile
`keytool -import -alias example -trustcacerts -file certificate.p7b -keystore keystroke.jks`

But I got this error
`keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate`

Comment: You need to have both the public and private key exported. I don't think p7b is the proper format but I could be wrong. It took me a while to get my keystore working with Javalin. What I ended up doing is downloading a tool called keystore explorer for Windows. Then I imported my wildcard cert. The jks file should have an entry type of key/value pair, the lock status should be locked and the rest is up to you. The keystore explorer provides a handy GUI for creating your jks file. :)